# How to interact with a json in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, loops

how is it going?
I'm pretty new in javascript and json, I've tried several things like loop, but I'm stuck. I'm trying to get a description of a fruit or vegetable through an id. How would you guys do it?

I have the following nested json...

```
CATEGORIES = [{
        'title': 'vegetables:',
        'items': [
            {
                'id': '19',
                'description': 'asparagus',
            }
        ]
    },
{
        'title': 'Fruits:',
        'items': [
            {
                'id':'21',
                'description': 'oranges',
            },
            {
                'id': '22',
                'description': 'Apples',
            },
            {
                'id':'23',
                'description': 'pears',
            },
            {
                'id': '24',
                'description': 'limes',
            },
            {
                'id': '25',
                'description': 'avocados',
            },
        ]
    },]
```

Comment: what do you need as result? can you put your expeected result

Comment: I think this is what you want: =================>

let value
CATEGORIES.forEach(x=>{
const query=x.items.find(x=>x.id==19) 
   if(query!=null){
      value=query
   }
})